# On hover, change styles on parent and child using one CSS rule

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to change the div **AND** child css properties when I hover over the div, but using a single CSS statement.

Is there a way to combine these two CSS statements into a one:

```
div:hover{background-color:red}
```

and

```
div:hover .child{background-color:blue}
```

Comment: No because they are doing different things

Comment: You can make this happen using less

Comment: This is not possible, your selectors are targeting two different elements.

Comment: @Vishal Panara: No, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not combine different selector; they "select" different HTML elements and they apply different styles..
why do you want to combine two different things?

Comment: Thanks for the help